# Join and overwrite an attribute in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have this dataframe:

```
# data
data = [['london_1', 10,'london'], ['london_2', 15,'london'], ['london_3', 14,'london'],['london',49,'']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['station', 'info','parent_station'])
```

So:

```
    station  info parent_station
0  london_1    10         london
1  london_2    15         london
2  london_3    14         london
3    london    49
```

I would like to overwrite the `info` value of the child station according to the `info` value of the parent station:

```
    station  info parent_station
0  london_1    49         london
1  london_2    49         london
2  london_3    49         london
3    london    49
```

Is there a simple way to do that ?

Additional information:

- There could be more than one parent station, but only one parent station per station.

Comment: sure you look for simple way to do but you show no code you try not simple

Comment: @drec4s yes thats eaxctly what i assume. why assume otherwise? how can i know

Comment: so its not an assumption at all. it is what the question says

Comment: @athing Well, what about starting by asking the OP what did he tried?

Comment: @athing no, they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map` then condition assign

```
df.loc[df.parent_station.ne(''),'info'] = df.parent_station.map(df.set_index('station')['info'])
df
Out[329]: 
    station  info parent_station
0  london_1  49.0         london
1  london_2  49.0         london
2  london_3  49.0         london
3    london  49.0
```